# Returning a value from inside a promise which is in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to return the userRecord from inside the `getUserRecordFromAuth` function in firebase and to use it to get the user's `UID` from Authentication in Firebase.

The problem is that the userRecord.uid is always returning `undefined`, even though I'm returning the value of the promise in the `getUserRecordFromAuth()`. What gives?

```
const getUserData = mobile => {
    const userRecord = getUserRecordFromAuth(mobile);

    console.log('uid', userRecord.uid);
}

const getUserRecordFromAuth = mobile => {

    const promise = auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(mobile);

    return promise.then(userRecord => {
        return userRecord;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: `getUserRecordFromAuth(...).then(....)`

Comment: You're not "returning the value of the promise" (which is impossible, as it will only become available in the future), but rather you are returning the promise itself.

Comment: To achieve the same result in a more imperative looking fashion, similar to your code, you may also use [`asyc - await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) abstraction with promise returning async functions.

Comment: @Bergi Any propositons about the value returning promises that i can check. What would be difference from async/await..?

Answer (score 2):

As you are returning a Promise to get the result you need to use `.then()`

```
const getUserData = mobile => {
    getUserRecordFromAuth(mobile)
     .then((userRecord) => console.log('uid', userRecord.uid));
}
```

Comment: What if I want to return the userRecord from the getUserData. Getting the value inside the `then()` method will only keep my userRecord in a limited scope. How do I return the whole userRecord?